# Difference between V+着+V and 一边+V+一边+V

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between:

他们说着话吃饭。
他们一边说话一边吃饭。

他骑着自行车听音乐。
他一边骑自行车一边听音乐。

Thx

Comment: dict。cn：一边 ... 一边 at the same time，simultaneously，V1＋着＋V2: V2 while V1 cf. grammar on aspect particle 着,e.g.＂实用现代汉语语法＂３９３页（二）＂着＂的用法。当＂着＂表示状态的持续时，其作用主要在于描写，可用于以下情况：１。用于连动句的第一动词后，表示动作者‌​进行第二个动作（主要的动作）时的状态或方式，即表示一种伴随的动作。例如：１我微笑着淡淡地说。２鲁班含着眼泪拜别了师傅，下山了。３他拿着一张图片给我们仔细讲解，非常‌​清楚明白。４忽然，天空暗了下来，北风卷着大雪，向草原扑来。５忽然，海员们扶着一个老工人走过来。６欧阳海带着七班的战士走在最后边。这种连动句中带＂着＂的部分，具有明‌​显的描写作用，不少语发者作把它归入状语。２。连动句的第一动词（或形容词）后用＂着＂，也表示方式或状态，后面的第二个动词或动词短语表示原因或目的，这样用的＂动（形）‌​＋＇着＇＂也具有描写作用。例如：１他闹着让我带他出去玩儿。意思是：他为了让我带他出去玩而闹着（比如＂哭＂、＂叫＂等等）。２老王急着赶火车，饭也没吃就走了。意思是：‌​老王为了赶火车而着急。。。３他们忙着布置房间。意思是：他们因为布置房间而忙碌。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the emphasis appears to be different in these two forms. If I use `verb1` + 着 + [`verb1 complement`] + `verb2` + [`verb2 complement`], the second verb is *to me* a more important action. For example, I would interpret 你不应该听着音乐做功课 as *"You mustn't listen to music while doing homework"* and 你不应该做着功课听音乐 as *"You mustn't do homework while listening to music"*. These are not the same. If I want to tell someone that to focus on her homework, I use the first sentence. If I want someone to focus on the music we are listening to (so as to better appreciate it), I would use the second sentence.

In comparison, if I use 一边 + `verb1` + 一边 + `verb2`, there is less of an implicit emphasis on either action. If I see 你不应该一边等巴士，一边拍照, my interpretation is that it does not matter whether the person addressed stops taking photographs and waits for the bus, or gives up waiting for the bus and takes more photographs.

Comment: Perfect! I felt some difference between them, but I couldn't explain it better than you did.

Answer (score 0):

我哭着唱歌。哭着 sounds to turn into kind of adv., describing a status before another verb.

我一边哭一边唱。哭and 唱 are still two actions happening at the same time.

I am singing with tears. 我哭着唱歌。
I am singing while Weeping.我一边哭一边唱。

Actually, not much difference. V着v, sounds more colloquial, 一边v一边v，sounds more formal and literal.