# What does the zhe 着 after a verb do?

Tags: meaning

mdbg.net has for zhe 着： aspect particle indicating action in progress

That implies it corresponds with -ing. Many times however, I find 着 cannot be translated in this way.

What does 着 do? What difference does it make if it were not used?

From 父亲去世了

他光着脚，手指弯曲着，失去了往日的力量。
His leg bared, fingers bent, gone his former strength.
他的眼睛紧闭着，像两个黑洞。
His eyes tightly closed, like 2 black holes.
嘴巴张着，牙齿都露了。
Mouth open, teeth revealed.

Comment: I think 着 is not -ing , it is -ed is better . 闭着 :closed 闭: close 张着 :opened 张 :open . Add 着 to change a verb to a adj/adv. of course sometimes maybe -ing is right,eg:他一边在关着(closing)阀门，一边在看着(looking)压力表.

Comment: 着 is a heteronym in Chinese. What you ask is pronounced "zhe", and the explanation of it is 表示动作或状态在持续。I think you can translate it into-ing in some sentence, and sometimes you can translate it into still, such as 饭还热着。which in English :The food is still hot.

Comment: see grammars, e.g. ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂动作的持续（continuous aspect of an action)一，表示动作在持续的形式｜汉语里要表示一个动作或动作结果的状态在持续，可在谓语词后边加动态助词＂着（zhe）＂。基本格式是：主语－谓语（动词）－＂着＂－（宾语）｜例如：他眼睛闭着。（＂闭＂的动作在持续）那个妇女抱着一个男孩子。（＂抱＂的动作在持续）窗户开着，门关着。（＂开＂和＂关＂的动作已经完成，但＂开＂和＂关＂的状态仍在持续）她穿着一件黄衬衫。（＂穿＂的动作已经完成，＂穿＂的结果的状态仍在持续）to be distinguished from 动作的进行（progressive aspect of an action, search site) 一。表示动作正在进行的形式｜汉语里，要表示一个动作正在进行，可以在谓语动词前边加副词＂正＂、＂在＂或＂正在＂，句尾加上语气助词＂呢＂。基本格式是：１。主语－状语（副词＂正＂、＂在＂或＂正在＂）－谓语（动词）－（宾语）－（呢）

Comment: 例如：他们正开会（呢）。（＂开会＂的动作正在进行）（开会 is going on)他们在休息（呢）（＂休息＂正在进行）（休息 is going on)她们正在晒衣服（呢）。（＂晒衣服＂的动作正在进行）（晒衣服 is going on)）他们正在调查（呢）。（＂调查＂正在进行）（调查 is going on)）动作的持续和进行可以同时发生。（continuation and progression of an action may take place simultaneously)例如: 他正打着电话呢。她在织着毛衣呢。我们正在谈着话呢,  regarding in particular examples in Q, see http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17535/difference-between-v%E7%9D%80v-and-%E4%B8%80%E8%BE%B9v%E4%B8%80%E8%BE%B9v

Comment: 饭还热着。 is ambiguous, at least without context. It can also mean "The food is still warming up." in a microwave or somewhere.

Comment: commonly: the food is still being heated in the microwave oven:饭还在微波炉中在加热

Comment: Note that these "verbs" are usually considered adjectives in the English grammar. So if you want to add -ing in an overly literal way, it should be "being closed" "being warm", instead of "closing" "warming".

Answer (score 3):

着 is used to express that something is in the **status** of a verb, so it should not be progressive. For example "sitting" is 坐着.

Examples:

他光着脚，手指弯曲着，失去了往日的力量。
His leg bared(baring), fingers bent(bending), gone his former strength.

Counter-examples:
您做着什么？ This one is invalid

The verb "do" is progressive(this action is changing), so 着 is not used here.

Answer (score 1):

If I say 他坐着，this instance sounds incomplete. If I say 他正坐着, it sounds complete. This contrast indicates that 着 in Chinese is merely used to indicate a duration, without involving the tense relating to the now.

Answer (score 1):

It's like a "to be participle". It's not actually "to be -ing".

Compare:
门开着。 The door **is opened**.
他在开门呢。 He is **opening** the door.

You can understand it as a -ing construction only if it follows another verb. In that case, it's like someone does something while **doing** something.

For example:
他开着门开灯了。 He turned the lights on while **opening** the door.

Hope this helps. Cheers.